# How to wait for function to finish in express route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this route:

```
   app.get("/api/current_user", (req, res) => {

    //This function takes 3~ seconds to finish
    someObj.logOn(data => {
      someObj.setData(data);
    });

    //This will return before function finishes
    return res.send(someObj.data);
  });
```

Here is the .logOn() function (simplified):

```
logOn(_callback) {
  //has some data
  var info = {};

  //returns data in callback
  _callback(info);
}
```

**Question:** Is there some way to to wait for the function to finish before returning? This function does not deal with promises, so I cannot use async/await. I couldnt find any good answers, and anything with waiting either had to deal with promises or setTimeout. Both of which would not work, right?

**Note:** If I put the return statement inside the callback right under `someObj.setData(data);` I will get an error like this:

> can't set headers after they are sent

This error occurs not on the intial route load, but after I refresh one more time.

Comment: you can return immediately, but send data in a asynchronous callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a callback. Changing res.send to res.end so that no headers are set. It seems that something is written to the response in the functions we can't see.

```
 app.get("/api/current_user", (req, res) => {

    //This function takes 3~ seconds to finish
    someObj.logOn(data => {
      someObj.setData(data);
      res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
  });
```

Comment: Yup, this is what I suggested.

Comment: If I put return statement inside the callback I will get a "cant set headers error"

Comment: Should've added that, one sec

Comment: Return statement gone - not needed. Not sure why you would get a can't set headers unless you are trying to set headers somewhere after this.

Comment: The route works error free once I put the return statement outside of the callback. Only problem is since its asynchronous the return comes before the data. When it's inside the callback I get the error on a refresh

Comment: Let me try removing the null,2.. that was accidentally left there from JSON.stringify() arguments

Comment: Still didn't fix it, also I updated that part on the post now

Comment: Perhaps it is an error somewhere else in the code... I just cant find it. It doesn't seem like the simplified code I posted seems to have any error at first glance?

Comment: And using res.end() just threw an error of, TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer

Comment: What is the type of data? If it is an object, try one of either res.json(data) or res.end(JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: OMG! That worked!! res.end(JSON.stringify(data)).. But why! Can res.send() not send objects? You can put the answer in an edit and ill mark it correct

Comment: Will update the answer. The problem is that some code, probably in your login is sending a response that doesn't allow any other responses to be sent. Because of this, res.end will be the only response that you can send after that.